# Wondering if I can manage Font Awesome Kit on v6 using nom or package manager

Tags: font-awesome, package-managers, font-awesome-6

Has anyone been able to implement the management of a Font Aweseom Kit adding new custom icons as a self-hosted version using npm or any other package management system? So for instance we add a custom icon to the Kit then increment the version and update our package.json to go get that version of the Kit and place it in the node_modules dir?